# Цикл php не выводит информацию

Tags: php, циклы

Почему не выводит информацию в данном цикле?

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
for ($tt = 1 ; $tt == 10; $tt++){
    echo "{$tt}-ый раз<br>";
}
echo "{$tt} op";
?>
```

Comment: в конце точку с запятой поставь. То что выведется, это отдельный разговор))

Comment: Поправил  , но инфа из циклы не выводится

Comment: потому что не проходит проверку $tt == 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя ошибка в цикле, ты просто приравниваешь $tt == 10, а нужно видимо $tt < 10

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
for ($tt = 1 ; $tt < 10; $tt++){
    echo "{$tt}-ый раз<br>";
}
echo "{$tt} op";
?>
```

Comment: Не приравнивает, а сравнивает.

Answer (score 3):

У вас в условии цикла стоит `$tt == 10`, цикл даже не начинает выполняться, т.к. на первой итерации `$tt` = 1, а не 10. Замените условие на это $tt < 10, например